# How did Palpatine prevent Anakin from being targeted by Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, darth-sidious, anakin-skywalker

In the current canon, the success of Order 66 was assured by an inhibitor chip implanted in all clones to ensure total compliance when Order 66 is issued, overriding all conscious control by the clone to prevent any attempt to resist the Order, an otherwise highly likely reaction due to the respect, friendship and loyalty the clones have developed with the Jedi over the course of the war.

How did Palpatine ensure that Anakin would be an exception? Clearly, Palpatine planned to execute Order 66 after Anakin is turned to the dark side. But how did he manage to get the inhibitor chip to not include Anakin in the list of targets without Dooku (who was responsible for running the whole cloning operation while still an apprentice to Palpatine) finding out?